# Saving photo with transparent background to Contacts

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap, android-vectordrawable

I want to add a contact to the android contacts database which is working fine. As a Contact Photo there is a Vector from resource which gets converted to a Bitmap and then into a ByteArray like this:

```java
    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(Context context, int drawableId) {
        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId);
        drawable = (DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable)).mutate();

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setARGB(255,255,255,255);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), paint);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);

        return bitmap;
    }

    public static byte[] toByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }
```

So basically its saved as PNG, so it should be transparent, right? For me its not. Does the Contact database support transparency or did I miss something at converting the Bitmap?